# Can't run Node.js server local

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel

I can't npm run watch I don't know the problem

[image: Error message]

Comment: 1: do not post screenshots of text, post test. Read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and follow those guidelines 2: the text is _pretty obvious_ in that you're relying on `cross-env` but you don't have it installed. Install it (and if it's not in your package.json, --save it this time).

Comment: hey i have package.json but it isn't unknow

Comment: I have no idea what you just said, so: run `npm install` to install all the necessary dependency, then also open package.json, look at the dependency list, and if `cross-env` is not listed, also run `npm install cross-env --save` so make sure it becomes a known dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it happened because some packages didn't install correctly.
to fix that run "npm install".

Please add more info in the question like what error you get or what step you did.

Comment: i can't run watch but there is package.json and i am do install for second

Comment: Edit your question and paste the error you get, if you want us to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is `Cross-env` is not installed in your environment..

delete `node_modules` DIR and try

> `npm i`
>
> `npm i -g cross-env`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use a dotenv-webpack plugin to use the env variable in webpack.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack

> `npm i dotenv-webpack`

In your webpack.config.js

> `plugins: [ new Dotenv({ path: path.resolve(__dirname,'./.env.dev'), })]`